# Unable to delete the data from the database using PDO and AJAX

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo

I am using the following code to delete the data from the database.

```
    <?php
//include database connection
include 'connect_db.php';

try {

    $query = 'DELETE FROM tasks WHERE task_id = ?';
    $stmt = $DBH->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['task_id']);
    var_dump($stmt);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        echo "Task was deleted.";
    }else{
        echo "Unable to delete Task.";
    }

}

//to handle error
catch(PDOException $exception){
    echo "Error: " . $exception->getMessage();
}
?>
```

But if I am calling this file with the following URL I am getting the following.
The data is not able to delete.

```
~delete.php?task_id=9

object(PDOStatement)#2 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(35) "DELETE FROM tasks WHERE task_id = ?" } Task was deleted.
```

**Ajax Function** 
I am using the following ajax function to delete the data.
     // when clicking the DELETE button

```
   $(document).on('click', '#deleteBtn', function(){ 
            if(confirm('Are you sure?')){

                // get the id
                var task_id = $(this).closest('td').find('#task_id').text();

                // trigger the delete file
                $.post("delete.php", { id: task_id })
                    .done(function(data) {
                        // you can see your console to verify if record was deleted
                        console.log(data);

                        $('#loaderImage').show();

                        // reload the list
                        showTasks();

                    });

            }
        });
```

Comment: I think you'll need to change your method from POST to GET/REQUEST. Try `$stmt->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['task_id']);`

Comment: According to that output the task was deleted.  Or at least that `echo` statement was reached in the code.  Was there an error from the database which wasn't caught?

Comment: I tried GET, logically , GET should be used, but I tried to use post as well, both of them are not working.

Comment: Are there constraints on your table that are not setup properly? Are you sure you are `POST`ing or `GET`ing?

Comment: The key in debugging probably lies in var_dump'ing $_POST['task_id']

Comment: Did you try `$stmt->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['task_id']);`? @MohitKumar

Comment: @David, The logic is working, but code is not able to delete the data from the database .I checked my SQL , it is OK , I am concerned about  ""DELETE FROM tasks WHERE task_id = ?"" Is it normal , that I am not able to see task_id = 9 ?

Comment: You tagged this as `ajax` you should show us what you have in there also. @MohitKumar

Comment: @Fred-ii- Added the code for ajax also

Comment: Since you're using a GET method passing it the way you're doing (`delete.php?task_id=9`), try changing `$.post("delete.php", { id: task_id })` to `$.get("delete.php", { id: task_id })` along with `$stmt->bindParam(1, $_REQUEST['task_id']);` @MohitKumar

Comment: @Fred-ii-  It is not able to delete it. I am attaching the data from the firebug. Everything is working OK , but the data is not able to delete from the DB `GET http://localhost/development/php/book/ToDo/delete.php?id=7` `200 OK` `2ms`   . However, if I run the same query on database it is able to delete ` 1 row deleted. (Query took 0.0660 sec)
DELETE FROM tasks WHERE task_id =7`
`jquery....min.js (line 4)
ParamsHeadersResponseHTMLCookies

Task was deleted.`

Comment: Why GET should be used ? This is not logic, for a delete operation, always prefer POST method. And... check the user has the permission to do it or somebody will hack your app.
Your problem is very easy to debug, just display the content of $_POST and debug the way it goes and the query...

Comment: @Loenix I am getting `NULL` for $_POST

Comment: Can you try your query as pure PHP with no Ajax to see if that will work? @MohitKumar If it does work, then you'll know right away that your Ajax is at fault. And using `?id...` is not a POST method, that's one reason why it's not showing in your `var_dump()`

Comment: @Mohit Kumar $_POST can not be null... If there is no data, this is an empty array.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried as you specified. Right now I am getting `string(0) for var_dump( $_POST['task_id']);` and it is still not able to remove the data from the DB.

Comment: Try `var_dump($_REQUEST['task_id']);` see what the results are. @MohitKumar

Comment: OK, it is working now with pure PHP with `$_REQUEST['task_id']`. But It is not working with AJAX, I will look more, seems like there is a problem with the Ajax code.

Comment: @MohitKumar That's great news, now to tackle Ajax ;-)